# Disable media key actions on KDE Plasma lock screen

Tags: kde, security, lock-screen, plasma, privacy

It is a neat feature that there is a whitelist for certain key actions while the KDE Plasma lock screen is active. These whitelisted actions include volume and brightness control, and also media key actions. Here's a bit of the [story behind it](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2015/02/global-shortcuts-and-the-lock-screen/).

And here is a question about how to [turn off the media control switches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127086/disable-display-of-media-controls-on-lock-screen-showmediacontrols-on-kde-plas) visible at the lock screen.

However, turning off the controls at the lock screen does not prevent the actions of media control keys (play/pause, switch track) to go through to any open applications playing media. This seems like a privacy concern to me.

Is there a way to deactivate media key actions when the lock screen is active? Or can the deactivation of graphical control switches be coupled to a deactivation of media key actions?

Comment: +1. Have you tried [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/) because that has the latest version of KDE Plasma? If what you've noticed is present there, consider filing a bug at https://bugs.kde.org/.

Comment: Yes, same behaviour on KDE neon 5.15 with Plasma 5.15.3. Thanks for your recommendation

Comment: Quite a few KDE Plasma devs respond at https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/. It maybe a good idea to post there as well.